# flink - An error occurred creating the temp table

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, gelly

Team,
  I am getting the below error in flink.

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:413)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:92)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:389)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:376)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:61)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:896)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.count(DataSet.java:394)
        at org.apache.flink.graph.Graph.numberOfVertices(Graph.java:1256)
        at com.phoenix.etl.job.AdJob.constructFlinkPlan(AdJob.java:330)
        at com.phoenix.etl.job.AdJob.execute(AdJob.java:97)
        at com.phoenix.etl.job.BatchJob.run(BatchJob.java:38)
        at com.phoenix.etl.job.AdJob.main(AdJob.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:509)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:403)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:331)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:777)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:253)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1005)
        at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1048)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$8.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:822)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$8.apply(JobManager.scala:768)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$8.apply(JobManager.scala:768)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred creating the temp table.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.TempBarrier.getIterator(TempBarrier.java:98)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.getInput(BatchTask.java:1094)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.JoinWithSolutionSetFirstDriver.run(JoinWithSolutionSetFirstDriver.java:155)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:486)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.iterative.task.AbstractIterativeTask.run(AbstractIterativeTask.java:146)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.iterative.task.IterationIntermediateTask.run(IterationIntermediateTask.java:92)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:351)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot instantiate tuple.
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.TupleSerializer.createInstance(TupleSerializer.java:70)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.TupleSerializer.createInstance(TupleSerializer.java:30)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.TempBarrier$TempWritingThread.run(TempBarrier.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at org.apache.flink.types.Either$Right.<init>(Either.java:148)
        at org.apache.flink.types.Either.Right(Either.java:46)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.EitherSerializer.createInstance(EitherSerializer.java:73)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.EitherSerializer.createInstance(EitherSerializer.java:37)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.TupleSerializer.createInstance(TupleSerializer.java:64)
        ... 2 more
```

Flink version - 1.1.0

Can you please throw some light on this. I am getting this while doing vertex centric graph traversal.

The vertex is a DataSet of Tuple2
and edge is a DataSet of Tuple3

For vertex and edge i am able to print the values using collect.

Regards,
Sajeev

Comment: If you post some code snippets, it is much easier to figure out what you are doing and what causes the problem. Without code it is pretty much wild guessing.

Comment: I could figure out the problem now. When I used the below code, it threw the above error. public void compute(Vertex<String, VertexT> v, MessageIterator<Map<String,String>> msgIter) throws IOException {                 But it worked when I used public void compute(Vertex<String, VertexT> v, MessageIterator<String> msgIter) throws IOException {

Comment: This shows that MessageIterator<String> only works and MessageIterator<Map<String,String>> throws exception

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late for you but can be helpful for others having the same problem with flink 1.2, I just found this thread because I was experiencing same issue and your comments helped me

It looks like you cannot use Interfaces, I got the same error with `compute(Vertex<String, VertexData> vertex, MessageIterator<Collection<MessageData>> messages)` or `compute(Vertex<String, VertexData> vertex, MessageIterator<List<MessageData>> messages)`

But it works with `compute(Vertex<String, VertexData> vertex, MessageIterator<LinkedList<MessageData>> messages)`